# Python strptime is unable to parse date

Tags: python, strptime

When I try to run the following code, I keep getting a value error even though the date as per my knowledge follows the format string specified.

```
try:
  datetime.datetime.strptime('23-Jan-2017 15:30:00', '%d-%B-%Y %H:%M:%S')
except ValueError as e:
  print('Not mathcing')
  traceback.print_exc()
```

Where am I going wrong? The date and the format matches with the given format string, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: your format should be `'%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S'`. see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=strptime#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a lowercase b for the month

```
'%d-%B-%Y %H:%M:%S'
```

should be

```
'%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S'
```

See [here](http://strftime.org/) for a full list of formatting values

```
%b  Month as locale’s abbreviated name. Sep
%B  Month as locale’s full name.    September
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write '%b' instead of '%B':

```py
datetime.datetime.strptime('23-Jan-2017 15:30:00', '%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Cheers!